# Deleting node from XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath

I'm very close. I'm ask to delete an entry from an XML FILE if the last name of an ASP TEXT BOX matches to an XML "entry".

Here is the button script. Please take note of XmlNode PhoneBook line:

```
protected void deletion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/PhoneBook.xml"));

    XmlElement root = document.DocumentElement;

XmlNode PhoneBook = document.SelectSingleNode("//event[@lastName='" + txtLastName.Text + "']");
    PhoneBook.ParentNode.RemoveChild(PhoneBook);

    document.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/PhoneBook.xml"));
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I keep getting errors, I'm guessing I'm not selecting the correct node in the xml file using SelectSingleNode?

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? Can you copy-paste the error message? Or is just the result different from what you expect? What do you expect?

Comment: Getting error with PhoneBook.ParentNode.RemoveChild(PhoneBook);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
XmlNode PhoneBook = document.SelectSingleNode("/phoneBook/entry[lastName/text()='" + txtLastName.Text + "']");
```

You're trying to filter on an `element`, not an `attribute` so you can't use the `@` sign.

This XPath returns the 2nd `entry` element (I tested it, it works):

```
/phoneBook/entry[lastName/text()='twoL']
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with the next line: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. PhoneBook.ParentNode.RemoveChild(PhoneBook);

Comment: That's because you're XPath is incorrect resulting in the `PhoneBook` node being `null`. What value are you testing with for the last name?

Comment: How do i delete an element now that's selected? :/

Comment: Just like you have it should work: `PhoneBook.ParentNode.RemoveChild(PhoneBook)`